# C# Windows Mouse Control

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mouse, theory

I am coding an application for a school project that said "Make something you are proud of without any prior knowledge or experience", and have encountered a situation where my lack of information counts as a roadblock.

I do not know and could not find any useful information on how the windows mouse wheel works, and how to include it in my program.

To simplify the issue: I need to control the mouse with code, the buttons work well, but I do not have a clue on how the mouse wheel works, and how I should implement it's movement.

The method I use for mouse events:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
```

If anyone could explain how the mouse wheel works in general, or how I should use the method to control it I would be very thankful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually figured it out by playing with the method, sorry to bother.

To give a mouse wheel movement to the pc, I just need to call the method with the correct dwFlag for the wheel and write the number of lines to scroll into the dwData parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> "Make something you are proud of without any prior knowledge or experience"

High five for that one, now let me explain in layman terms

> I do not have a clue on how the mouse wheel works

Your mouse works on the screen coordinates of your computer, for example, your screen resolution in 1024 x 768, so when you move your mouse physically you change the x and, y coordinates of your mouse relative to your screen.

[image: Have look at it]

Also, [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) is a great library to control mouse programmatically, it hides all the complexity and, let you just focus on the actions that you want to perform with mouse or keyboard.